# How to add Active WooCommerce Membership Plan Slug to Body Class?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-memberships

I'm setting up a membership site using WooCommerce, WooCommerce Subscriptions, and WooCommerce Memberships. Ideally, I would first like to check if the user is logged-in and if they have an active membership. Then, I want to add the active membership plan's slug to the page's body class.

I have code below which adds several classes to the page's body tag, including checking for a user's "Gold Membership" plan and adding it to the body tag.

```
/* Add Page Slug to Body Class */

add_filter( 'body_class', 'am_add_slug_body_class' );

function am_add_slug_body_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    if ( isset( $post ) ) {
        $classes[] = $post->post_type . '-' . $post->post_name;
    }
    return $classes;
}

/* Add Logged-Out Body Class */

add_filter('body_class','am_logged_in_filter');

function am_logged_in_filter($classes) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $classes[] = '';
    } else {
        $classes[] = 'logged-out';
    }
    return $classes;
}

/* Add Gold Membership to Body Class */

add_filter('body_class','am_membership_class_filter');

function am_membership_class_filter($classes) {
    if( wc_memberships_is_user_member( null, 'gold-membership' ) ) {
        $classes = 'gold-membership';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

However, this last "Gold Membership" function removes all other body classes that I have added prior, rendering any of my "Logged-In" or page-specific CSS non-functional.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the [] to $classes in your final if statement. It should look like this:

`$classes[] = 'gold-membership'`